# How to use NOT IN with Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, realm

I have a list of Realm objects (let's say User) and I want to retrieve all of them but "John", "Marc", "Al' Med" and so on.

I tried the following:

```
var namesStr = ""
for user in unwantedUsers {
    namesStr += "'" + user.name + "', "
}
namesStr = String(namesStr.characters.dropLast().dropLast())
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT name IN {%@}", namesStr)
let remainingUsers = uiRealm.objects(User).filter(predicate)
```

I also tried with `NSPredicate(format: "name NOT IN {%@}", namesStr)` but it would crash (exception raised).

And **second thing**, how am I suppose to escape the names in the NSPredicate. If one of the names has a **'** character, it won't probably work.

**EDIT**

Thanks to LE SANG, here's the functional result:

```
var userArr: [String] = []
for user in unwantedUser {
    userArr.append(user.name)
}
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT name IN %@", userArr)
let remainingUsers = uiRealm.objects(User).filter(predicate)
```

Comment: what 's [uiRealm.objects(Image)] ?

Comment: @NguyenHoan It's a typo, should be `uiRealm.objects(User)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: "How to NOT use Realm within Swift" /jk

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to the [Realm document](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries), these ways should work

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (name IN %@)", namesStr)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "!(name IN %@)", namesStr)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT name IN %@", namesStr)
```

Comment: Perfect! I misunderstood the document when it said `name IN {‘Lisa’, ‘Spike’, ‘Hachi’}`. And I don't even need to concat the array into a string anymore!

Comment: You can also use an array